# How to continuous apply a function to an argument?

Tags: functional-style, map

In order to calculate `x = sqrt(1 + x)` for a given number x, 40 times, I tried this:

```
f [x_] := Sqrt[1 + x]
N[Map[f, x = Range[40]]]
```

However, I got to apply the function f to every number from 1 to 40, not continuously.

The process should be 
    Sqrt[Sqrt[Sqrt...[1+x]]]

In Matlab, I could do

```
x = 3
for k = 1:41
    x = sqrt(1 + x)
end
```

Data in Mathematica is inmutable by default, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Nest` is probably what you need.

```
Nest[f, x, 40]
```

[image]

Also worth reading the docs for `Fold` and `FixedPoint`

Comment: Thank you, especially for pointing out the documentation. `FixedPoint` is also an interesting function.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[x_] = Sqrt[1 + x];
```

The fixed point is the golden ratio, independent of the starting value

```
(x /. Solve[x == f[x], x][[1]]) == GoldenRatio
```

> True

```
GoldenRatio == f[GoldenRatio] // FullSimplify
```

> True

```
FixedPoint[f, {.01, .1, 1., 1.1, 10.}] // Union
```

> {1.61803}

```
%[[1]] // RootApproximant
```

> 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])

```
% == GoldenRatio
```

> True

Comment: Yes, I'm leaning `Mathematica` by calculating the Golden Ratio. It's good to know that there's even a `GoldenRatio` built-in the Mathematica. Thank you!